# Variable not changed in custom initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, initialization

I am trying to set a value of variable in swift when initialising an instance of a UINavigationController subclass. The code looks like this:

```
private var initWithRootViewController = false

init() {
    super.init(rootViewController: contentVC)
    initWithRootViewController = true
}

init(parameters: OAuth2Parameters) {
    initWithRootViewController = true
    super.init(rootViewController: contentVC)
    initWithRootViewController = true
    //defer { initWithRootViewController = true }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

    //initWithRootViewController = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if !initWithRootViewController {
        setViewControllers([contentVC], animated: false)
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my custom initialiser (`init(parameters: OAuth2Parameters)`) the value of `initWithRootViewController` is never changed. I have even tried to set it before and after super.init is called as shown in the code and to set it after initialisation (commented `defer` line). Neither works. I have also tried to clean (and clean build folder) in Xcode and reset the simulator.

I inspected the value of `initWithRootViewController` by setting breakpoints. What I discovered was that in the custom initialiser the property changes value to `true`, but as soon as it goes out of the scope of the initialiser (when `init(nibName...)` is called), the value says `false` and it stays like that when inspected in  If I change the value in `init(nibName...)` then it is set properly. Why can I not change the value of the variable in my custom init method?

Comment: Weird.  Is `viewDidLoad` getting called before or after the part of `init(parameters:)` that is after the `super.init` call?

Comment: Why do you care where rootViewController get set just so long as it does? Why create a property to track this when you could just check `if self.viewControllers.count == 0`?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` gets called after both initialisers as expected. I actually tried to check the count of the view controllers, but it always returned 0 in `viewDidLoad`, which also is weird. What I did in the end was to call `super.init(nibName...)` instead of `super.init(rootViewController...)` and always set the rootViewController in `init(coder...)` and `init(nibName...)`.