# Create subclass of UIViewController with navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a custom class in the same way that Apple does their `MFMessageComposeViewController`, a custom class that can be initialised from code without any storyboards that has a navigation bar with the ability to push and pop and so on. So far my design has been to subclass `UINavigationController` and initialise it with a subclass of `UIViewController`. Let's call these classes `CustomClassVC` and `CustomClassContentVC` respectively. The code will therefore look something like this:

```
private let contentVC = CustomClassContentVC()

init() {
    super.init(rootViewController: contentVC)
}

init(parameters: CustomParameterClass) {
    super.init(rootViewController: contentVC)
    self.parameters = parameters
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

The first problem with this design is that for user friendliness I want users of the code to be able to say `CustomClassVC.myCustomProperty` instead of `CustomClassVC.contentVC.myCustomProperty`. I have solved this by creating properties in both classes, where the properties in `CustomClassVC` has setters and getters that access the equivalent properties in `CustomClassContentVC`. **So... First question: Is this a "correct" way of doing it, or is there a better way of achieving a view controller with a built in navigation bar?**

Next: If `CustomClassVC` is initialised by calling `init()` then all is fine. However, if for instance `init(nibName...)` is called directly then `CustomClassContentVC` will not be set as root view controller. Another related "problem" is that `init(rootViewController:...)` is calling `init(nibName...)` through the super class. This means that if I add `setViewControllers([contentVC], animated: false)` in the initialisers that are not setting the root view controller already, then they will always override `init(rootViewController:...)`. Therefore I cannot set the root view controller here. A solution to this is to assign a variable to whether or not `init()` has been called already or not, but it does not seem like a good solution (btw, I have tried this, but encountered a strange problem, [see here for details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755550/variable-not-changed-in-custom-initialiser). Another solution would be to set the root view controller in `init(nibName...`) and make `init()` a convenience initialiser, but it does not feel right when we have an initialiser made specifically to assign the root view controller during initialisation. **Therefore, question 2: How can I assign a root view controller and make sure that it is set properly regardless of which initialiser that's called?**

Comment: For your first problem: What you are doing is fine.  It's the same thing `MFMailComposeViewController` does.

Comment: For your second problem: I would call `super.init(nibName...)`  and then `setViewControllers(...)` in your custom initializers then don't implement `init(nibName..)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up doing as you recommend using `super.init(nibName...)`. Good to know that the architecture is the same as for `MFMailComposeViewController` as well.